# Passing variable values from one route to another in a token authenticated flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask token authenticated application implemented by flask jwt extended.

**Code**

```
import random
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "some secret key"
jwt = JWTManager(app)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
secret_email = "xxxx@gmail.com"
secret_pass = "password"

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return jsonify({"msg":"Hello, World!"})

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    email = request.json.get("email", None)
    password = request.json.get("password", None)
    if email != secret_email or password != secret_pass:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Bad username or password"}), 401

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=email)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token)

@app.route("/configs")
def configs():
    a = random.randint(10,30)
    b = random.randint(1,5)
    summ = a+b
    return jsonify({"a":a,"b":b})

@app.route("/sumcollect")
def sumcollect():
    return jsonify({"sum is":summ})
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

The `summ` variable in route `/configs` needs to be accessed in route `/sumcollect` . I tried with session variables. But the token authentication and session variables are not working together. Is there any way to pass the variables in this case.

Note: Just added django tag for this in case for them to look at to have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask , the method to send variables from one route to another is possible using the **redirect** function. Redirect function needs the url of the function and the values that is needed by the other route. For more information , you can refer : https://sodocumentation.net/flask/topic/6856/redirect

```
@app.route("/sumcollect")
def sumcollect():
    summ = request.args['summ']
    return jsonify({"sum is":summ})

@app.route("/configs")
def configs():
    a = random.randint(10,30)
    b = random.randint(1,5)
    summ = a+b
    return jsonify({"a":a,"b":b}),redirect(url_for('sumcollect',summ=summ))
```

Comment: both routes are called independently. First /configs route is called and then only /sumcollect is called. Its a fixed pattern. I am getting 500 Internal Server Error while trying to access.